# Retain select option value after submit in Django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am not using Ajax or django forms. I have plain HTML select tag inside the form tag and sending the selected option value in my view. I want to retain the select option value after the submission. Currently, it comes to default value of 1 irrespective of my selection. Help would be appreciated.

Here is my template code:

```
            <form method = "post" action = "{% url 'index' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label class="mainlbl">Vega</label>
                <select name = "drop1" >
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                </select>
                <input class="btn btn-ocean btn-side-bar" type = "submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

Here is my view for that:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        vega = request.POST['drop1']
        vega = int(vega)
        gvo = GVOptimize('NSE', 'Nifty')
        data = gvo.get_optimal_strategies(vega)
        str1 = None

        for i in range(0, len(data)):
            if i == 0:
                str1 = data[i]

            elif i == 1:
                str2 = data[i]

            elif i == 2:
                str3 = data[i]

            elif i == 3:
                str4 = data[i]

            else:
                break
        context_dict = {'str1': str1, 'str2': str2, 'str3': str3, 'str4': str4 'vega': vega}
        return render(request, 'demo/dashboard.html', context_dict)
    else:
        context_dict = {}
        return render(request, 'demo/dashboard.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a django form?

Comment: What is the point of that for loop? Why have four different `str*` variables, which you're only using to populate the context dict? Even if you don't know about dict comprehensions, why not just `context_dict = {'str1': data[0], ...}`?

Comment: @Sayse yup..I've got the front end already developed and don't want to play with the design part.

Comment: A form wouldn't affect the front end at all

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for the suggestion. Now, help would be appreciated in resolving the issue..

Comment: @Sayse can't it be possible without forms?

Comment: Oh sure you can pass back the selected index in the context and then check on every single option if the number equals the selected index and if so select it. (Hint: you could use a for loop for the options too). But that is an extremely hacky way of getting around the fact you could do with a form here.

Comment: @Sayse thanks! I need a hacky way right now :) Can you explain it with the code?

Answer (score 2):

If you really insist on having a hacky way of maintaining the selected option you can change your form to check every option to see if it equals the number you pass back in your context

```
<form method = "post" action = "{% url 'index' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label class="mainlbl">Vega</label>
    <select name = "drop1" >
        {% for idx in "useaformpls!" %}
            <option value="{{ forloop.counter }}" {% if context_val == forloop.counter %}selected {% endif %}>
                 {{ forloop.counter }}
             </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input class="btn btn-ocean btn-side-bar" type = "submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Where `context_val` equals the index you pass back in the context data of your view.

Comment: Dear future readers, I'm not proud of this code nor do I condone its usage.

Comment: Thanks! though the values in the dropdown are showing twice. I mean 1-12 and again 1-12

Comment: @RamanBalyan - Did you leave in your existing options code?.. that isn't possible from this snippet I've provided.

Answer (score 1):

**this answer is here only, because this is not how it should be resolved!**

you are using Django, so use Forms that are dedicated for such a use, there are many reasons why to use them, but there are few that matters:

- simple code
- straight-forward use of forms with generic views
- data validation (yes, you do not need to check if this is an integer, or if somebody is hacking your page and posting value outside of range that is in your `select`)
- data escape - yes, no more stupid security holes
- validation tied to form elements, allowing to resubmit data and display to the user where is exactly an error

and don't tell me that this is more work...

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    drop1 = forms.IntegerField('Vega', choices=[(x,x) for x in range(1, 13)])
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    context_dict = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            vega = form.cleaned_data['drop1']
            gvo = GVOptimize('NSE', 'Nifty')
            data = gvo.get_optimal_strategies(vega)
            (str1, str2, str3, str4) = data[:4]
            context_dict = {'str1': str1, 'str2': str2,
                            'str3': str3, 'str4': str4 'vega': vega}
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    context_dict['form'] = form

    return render(request, 'demo/dashboard.html', context_dict)
```

dashboard.html

```
{% if form.is_valid %}
    <p>Vega: {{ vega }}</p>
{% else %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'index' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input class="btn btn-ocean btn-side-bar" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a good practice but you may try creating a function in your view.

```
def send_selected_combo(self):
    value_from_select = self.request.GET.get('select_html')
    return value_from_select
```

Then in your template you can call the function.

```
<select name="select_html" selected="id_selector">
    <option value="combo_value" {%if.view.send_selected_combo=="combo_value"%} selected {%endif%}></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select name = "drop1" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

When you submit the form in views.py you can use

```
selected_value = request.POST.get("drop1"); // If incase you are using get method which you shouldn't then use request.GET.get("drop1")
```